# Where are my saves?

Tags: sid-meiers-railroads

I noticed while I was playing that the game tells me often that it has saved. I assumed that meant that if I quit, I could come back later, and my game would be there, at the last save point, and I didn't need to manually save.

However, I came back to the game today, and my save was nowhere to be found. I am not sure if the game just puts them in a strange place (when you load a game, you can tell it where to look in the directory), or if it somehow decided not to actually save my game, despite many messages during my play that told me it was.

Knowing where the saves are normally located might help me determine where the games are being saved, but I don't see anywhere in the directory that looks likely.

Where are my saves?

Comment: `Documents -> My Games -> Sid Meier's Railroads -> Saves -> Auto` no luck?

Comment: I checked, and there's no saves folder in my Railroads folder...

Comment: [The official support site's answer](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/201333893-Where-can-I-find-my-Sid-Meier-s-Railroads-save-games-)

Comment: ....awesome. So not at all where the game THINKS they are by default. But hey, I found them. Thanks! (

Comment: ... So, wait, I was right? Because that's exactly the same thing I said. wat.

Comment: Yeah, you were. I just apparently suck at reading.